# How do I show grouped rows from model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model:

```rb
class Row < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :description
    attr_accesible :id, :q_id, :quantity, description_id
end

class Description < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :rows
    translate :description #globalize3, ignore it.
    attr_accesible :id, :other
end
```

In this case, `Description` and `Row` have a 1:N relationship (N from 1 to 3).

What is the best way to show this in table format in Haml?  For example if we have in the DB:

```
Row:
1 | 1 | 20 | 1
2 | 2 | 22 | 1
3 | 1 | 30 | 2
4 | 3 | 31 | 2
5 | 2 | 32 | 2

Description:
1 | asd
2 | zxc
```

I would like to show this form:

```
desc | q1 | q2 | q3 |
-----+----+----+----+
asd  | 20 | 22 | -- |
zxc  | 30 | 32 | 31 |
```

**UPDATE**

I added a new attribute (`q_id`) that indicates the "q" position (1, 2, or 3) to my Row model.

Comment: which db you are using ?

Comment: I think db is not relevant, but I'm using Postgres.

Comment: not relevant ? have you considered pivoting tables ?

Comment: nope. But I'm confused if I do something like Description.all.each do |desc| or Row.all.each do |row| and what I need to do inside loop

Comment: You don't need to do any fancy looping - just eager load the Rows while loading the Descriptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller code:

```
@descriptions = Description.eager_load(:rows).order('descriptions.id, rows.q_id')
```

In your view:

```
%table
  %tr
    %th= 'desc'
    %th= 'q1'
    %th= 'q2'
    %th= 'q3'
  - @descriptions.each do |description|
    %tr
      %td= description.description
      - (0..2).each do |i| 
        %td= description.rows[i].try(:quantity) || '--'
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to limit the rows to a specific user association, you can do so like this:

```
@descriptions = Description.eager_load(:rows).
                  where(rows: {user_id: some_user.id}).
                  order('descriptions.id, rows.q_id')
```

If you are concerned that this may exclude a description that has no matching rows, you can substitute a SQL fragment with a NULL alternative:

```
    @descriptions = Description.eager_load(:rows).
                  where('rows.user_id = ? OR rows.id IS NULL', some_user.id).
                  order('descriptions.id, rows.q_id')
```

Comment: Ok, and what happens if Row belongs to another (parent) model, for example an User. in this way is possible get rows from only one user?

Comment: @papelucho: there are a few ways to do this.  The simplest approach would be to add a where clause to limit those rows to the desired user (or `nil` if there is a possibility that no rows will be found for a particular description).  I'll update my answer to show how to do this.

Comment: I updated the question. I forgot an attribute, my apologies. Please check the resultant table.

Comment: @papelucho: updated answer to use the `q_id` field for sorting.

Comment: good, it works perfectly. Now I have to add a new table row and save into database.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
%table
  %tr
    - Description.includes(:rows).find_each do |description|
      %td= description.description
      %td= format_quantity description.rows.first
      %td= format_quantity description.rows.second
      %td= format_quantity description.rows.third
```

And a helper function

```
def format_quantity(row)   
  row.present? ? row.quantity : '--' 
end
```

**UPDATE**

For the order of rows, you could specify that on your relation

```
class Description < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :rows, order: 'q_id'
```

Comment: Right idea, except that this is subject to N+1, and this doesn't guarantee the order of the rows in PostgreSQL, and this doesn't output the row quantity

Comment: It works fine too, but @PinnyM's reply fits better to my needs.